# Clone multiple input values into one input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to copy the input data of multiple fields into one big one, for date of birth.

day value + month value + year value = day value/month value/year value into one other field all together. I made variables of each field and then try to add them in the 'full' input field, but this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/J2PHq/

```
$(function(){
    $('.copy').on('keyup blur', function(){
         $('.full').val(day + '/' + week + '/' + year);

        day = $(".day").val();
        week = $(".week").val();
        year = $(".year").val();
     }).blur();
});
```

Comment: you're fist appending the values and then getting them which is the wrong order, also you might want to use `var` to define variables

Comment: updated working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J2PHq/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the variables before you enter them in the `.full` field.

Working fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/J2PHq/3/)

```
$(function(){
    $('.copy').on('keyup blur', function(){        
        var day = $(".day").val();
        var week = $(".week").val();
        var year = $(".year").val(); 

        $('.full').val(day + '.' + week + '.' + year);

     }).blur();
});
```

Comment: It is always good to have both in the answer, so all users may get the solution at any time whenever JSFiddle.net works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong execution order -

```
$(function(){
    $('.copy').on('keyup blur', function(){
        var day = $(".day").val();
        var week = $(".week").val();
        var year = $(".year").val();
        $('.full').val(day + '/' + week + '/' + year);
     }).blur();
});
```

Demo `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/J2PHq/6/

Comment: Say **NO** to global variables!

Comment: Thanks, indeed the execution order.