# Get dynamic inputs value from one string input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I have followed this Question to get all inputs value into one input value and it's working fine: [Clone multiple input values into one input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713994/clone-multiple-input-values-into-one-input-field)

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yt4qeo6k/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(function(){
      $('.copy').on('keyup blur', function(){        
          var bgcolor = $(".bgcolor").val();
          var textcolor = $(".textcolor").val();
          var padding = $(".padding").val();
          var linkcolor = $(".linkcolor").val(); 

          $('.full').val( '#masthead {background-color:' + bgcolor + ';color:' + textcolor + ';padding:' + padding + 'px;} #masthead a{color:' + linkcolor + ';}');

       }).blur();
  });
});
```

```html
// Body Classes
function setting_dynamic_body_classes() { ?>
<input type="text" name="dynamic-bg-color" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="bgcolor copy color-picker" value="">
<input type="text" name="dynamic-text-color" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="textcolor copy color-picker">
<input type="range" name="dynamic-padding" class="rangeslider padding copy"  value="" step="1" min="0" max="100">
<input type="text" name="dynamic-link-color"  data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="linkcolor copy color-picker">
<input type="text" name="dynamic-body-classes" id="dynamic-body-classes" value="" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="full" style="width:100%;"/><br>
<strong>current Value: </strong><?php echo get_option('dynamic-body-classes'); ?>
<?php }
```

the Field dynamic-body-classes is saved in a custom options page in Wordprsss.
Now the issue after saving the form in Wordpress the Inputs value is empty because only the field "dynamic-body-classes" was saved in the database.

and the value of "dynamic-body-classes" e.g will look like following:

```html
#masthead {background-color:#1e73be;color:#dd9933;padding:95px;} #masthead a{color:#81d742;}
```

How can i add the value of each field (dynamic-bg-color, dynamic-bg-color, dynamic-padding, dynamic-link-color ) based on the value "dynamic-body-classes" ?

[before changing the values of each field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4BFQ.png)

[after changing the values of each field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TShV.png)

[After Saving the form the current value is showing up as expected but the dynamic field are empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fVnl.png)

I am not sure i am doing this the right way, but what i need is to add many dynamic fields that their value get saved as css in one field for dynamic Theme styling.

Comment: Really not enough known about how this is saved or where the code is to update the fields

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, i have edited the question. Its saved in a custom Theme options page in wordpress. please see attached images.

Comment: Suggest using a more structured object for your saving process is the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to extract the values from the saved string, here is an example:

```js
const full = $("#currentValue").text();
const values = full.match(/#masthead {background-color:([^;]+);color:([^;]+);padding:([^;]+)px;} #masthead a{color:([^;]+);}/);

$(".full").val(full);
$(".bgcolor").val(values[1]);
$(".textcolor").val(values[2]);
$(".padding").val(values[3]);
$(".linkcolor").val(values[4]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="dynamic-bg-color" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="bgcolor copy color-picker" value="">
<input type="text" name="dynamic-text-color" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="textcolor copy color-picker">
<input type="range" name="dynamic-padding" class="rangeslider padding copy"  value="" step="1" min="0" max="100">
<input type="text" name="dynamic-link-color"  data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="linkcolor copy color-picker">
<input type="text" name="dynamic-body-classes" id="dynamic-body-classes" value="" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="full" style="width:100%;"/><br>
<strong>current Value: </strong><span id="currentValue">#masthead {background-color:#1e73be;color:#dd9933;padding:95px;} #masthead a{color:#81d742;}</span>
```